# Deleted multiple items from multiple sublists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a function that erase multiple elements (which are equal to 0) of multiple sublist that are part of a list. The problem is that when I create my fuction, it returns me a big list without my sublists, so I want to know how can I say to python that removes that elements but leaves my sublist as the originals.

This is my code

```
def cero (data):
    lista=[]
    for list in data:
       for item in list:
           if item >0:
               lista.append(item)
    return (lista)
```

Comment: Could you provide some input/output/expected output toy data? Also, it may be a good idea to go through [here](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append the elements that match in a single list, so you got a single list as result, you may reproduce the original structure

```
def cero (data):
    result = []
    for list in data:
        subresult = []
        for item in list:
            if item >0:
                subresult.append(item)
        result.append(subresult)
    return result
```

Or using list comprehension grammar

```
def filter_list(values):
    return [[x for x in sublist if x > 0] for sublist in values]
```

Comment: This has solved the problem. Very speedy help indeed.Thank you

Comment: @N99 You're welcome, you can now think about accepting the answer (and vote up if you want) ;)